I'm facing the issue "ALPythonTools::eval python object not found onSoundDetected"
I'm trying to add face detection to my project, and I'm facing an issue concerning the sound detection.
I edited my code to create 2 classes for face detection and audio detection so that the robot only record the prompt if the user is facing it. Here is the code:
However, when I try to trigger the sound detection function, I have the following error :
[E] 16580 qitype.dynamicobject:         ALPythonTools::eval python object not found onSoundDetected
I only get it when i make sound around the robot so I know the event is triggered, but the function isnt called properly. What can I do ?
